# Exporting CSS in the context of a React App

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I am building a React App and using `.scss` to style my components. I am not using css modules for various reasons.

I'm now in a situation where I need to generate a `.css` file within my React App that is leveraging the app's `.scss` files. External assets need to be able to point to the `.css`.

So I went into the app, thinking I could created a file called `vendors.scss` file and that by omitting the underscore, React would know to compile a file called `vendors.css`. However, this didn't happen.

How do I compile a `.css` file that can be referenced externally within a React App?

Comment: I think you should eject react-app and manually make edits in webpack.config. Check https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/how-to-add-sass-or-scss-to-create-react-app-c303dae4b5bc for details.

Comment: Hi, I've ejected my React App previously (in order to get Sass Loaders up and running). But from what I can tell, Sass isn't actually compiling a referenceable file. `styles.scss` doesn't compile to `styles.css` like when you might be running Sass straight out of a Terminal window. I need an actual file to be output. So that it is referenceable elsewhere.